# Retrieve a SubString from a String in the fastest possible way. Format from the end is fixed but not from the beginning, and Length is also not fixed

Tags: javascript, string

I have a String which contains the current location of a person. Now i want to retrieve two strings which appears before the city name, the string is like here

```
Unnamed Road, Lal Qila, Chandni Chowk, New Delhi, City 110006, India.
```

here I want to extract `Chandni Chowk, New Delhi`. But also remember city name can be of any length. Below is my code can u pls reduce the time complexity

```
var c = 0;
            var arr = [];
            for(var i = location.length - 15; i >= 0; i--){
                if (c > 2) {
                    break;
                }
                if (location[i] == ",") {
                    c++;
                    arr.push(i);
   //               arr[c] = i;
                }
            }
            if (c == 2) {
                final_location = location.substring(arr[1] + 2, arr[0]);
            } else if (c == 3){
                final_location = location.substring(arr[2] + 2, arr[0]);
            }
```

**Thanks a lot guys for all of ur help**

Comment: How is the format of the address?

Comment: Unnamed Road, Lal Qila, Chandni Chowk, New Delhi, City 110006, India

Comment: Java is not Javascript

Comment: Is this format *fixed*?

Comment: yes from the end City 110006, India is fixed here 110006 is the pin code which will be of size 6

Comment: IF the format is **fixed**, you can split string by comma, get 3rd and 4th substring

Comment: use regular expressions

Comment: @AlexK. I put it back to Javascript since he added some JS code to the quesion

Comment: Actually guys Format from the end is fixed but not from the beginning. And yea its javascript code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the formatting is fixed from the end you could use it this way, **This is an edit based on the op's request**

```
var split = 'Unnamed Road, Lal Qila, Chandni Chowk, New Delhi, City 110006, India'.split(',');

var Area= split[split.length-5];// will have Chandni Chowk
var City= split[split.length-4];// will have New Delhi
```

Comment: Format from the end is fixed but not from the beginning

Comment: then what you can do is , get split.length and split[split.length-4] will give city name and split[split.length-5] will give you the area

Comment: Can you pls tell me what will be its complexity O(n) or constant ??

Comment: Length is also not fixed now how can i do split.length-5 or split.length-4 ??

Comment: Doesn't matter what the length may be, it'll give you what you want if the end is formatted correctly

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
var parts = addrString.split(',').slice(2, 4).toString();

> "Chandni Chowk, New Delhi"
```

After your comment, offset from the total length:

```
var addr = "Unnamed Road, Lal Qila, XXXXX, Chandni Chowk, New Delhi, City 110006, India"

var arr = addr.split(',');
var parts = arr.slice(arr.length - 4, arr.length - 2).toString();

> "Chandni Chowk, New Delhi"
```

Comment: Format from the end is fixed but not from the beginning

Comment: Can you pls tell me what will be its complexity O(n) or constant ??

Comment: For a single string thats indescribably irrelevant, are you doing this in a batch?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur I told you not to worry about complexity since your input size is **bounded**. For this kind of code, the top priority is readability.

Comment: Ok @dici i got you...:)

Comment: Alex Length is also not fixed now how can i do arr.length-5 or arr.length-4

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[^,]*,[^,]*(?=,\\s*\\bCity 110006\\b)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cQ9mY0/1)

Comment: Well, he said *fastest*. Regex are pretty slow, and overkill for a comma-separated string, aren't they ?

Comment: What if the location changes? Split won't work in this case.

Comment: What if there is not "City 110006" in the string ? You must assume a format to do things like that, and making assumptions also makes it faster in this case. A regex itself **is** the description of a format

Comment: There will be a (city pincode, India) and it is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Just split the string by comma. To make it faster, compile the pattern just once and use it several times :

```
Pattern commaSeparated = Pattern.compile(",");
...
String address = "Unnamed Road, Lal Qila, Chandni Chowk, New Delhi, City 110006, India";
String[] split = commaSeparated.split(address);
// get the indices you want in split
```

Comment: My complexity is still better takes constant time pls try to reduce it.

Comment: look what i am doing is from last 16th character trying to find before two commas so that will take time but i guess in your way i have to examine the whole string thats why i am saying my approach is better

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur first, talking about complexity only makes sense if your data can become bigger and bigger. Your addresses, in the real world, will never exceed a certain limit, so the notion of complexity does not apply. The notion of **readability** applies however, and your code is not readable. Don't try to optimize a code which probably runs pretty fast already, find your **real** bottlemecks and tweek them.

Comment: Yes i am getting you @dici but i just want to reduce the time but thx anyways for ur help....:)

Comment: Did you measure it before thinking it needs to be reduced ? Never try to optimize something you did not measure, you might end up with a horribly complex code which brings no performance improvement

Answer (score 0):

If the entrys are always seperated by ',' you can use something like:

```
String[] temp = entryString.split(",");
```

and your desired Strings would be found in temp[2] and temp[3].

Comment: My complexity is still better

Comment: Format from the end is fixed but not from the beginning